# LinAlgError: Singular matrix when solving linalg.inv with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

By executing `np.linalg.inv(S)`  I get always an error:

The original S is

```
matrix([[matrix([[6371.]]), matrix([[6371.]])],
        [matrix([[6371.]]), matrix([[6371.]])]], dtype=object)

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv
```

if I convert s to float64 S = S.astype(np.float64) the content of S is

```
matrix([[6371., 6371.],
        [6371., 6371.]])

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

How can I solve this issue? I know the determinant is 0, however, by using other approaches like SVD and QR I also get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following after converting S to float64:

```py
result = np.linalg.pinv(S)
```

This returns the pseudo inverse.